# How to use Spice MI 350 for testing the application I am developing?

Tags: android, audio-recording

I am a new android developer. Currently I am working on an application which provides audio / video recording from device. Since the Android developers documentation suggests that We cant use emulator for Media recording. I want to use my Spice MI 350 for testing the application. For that purpose I have tried following [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html), However So far I couldn't get it working.

When I run `adb devices` I get ???????? as device name, the Device Chooser which appears just before running the application also displays ???????.

How do I get my Spice MI 350 (Android 2.3.3) available for testing the applications I develop (or I am trying to develop) ?

Comment: What is the minSdk Version that you've set for your project?

Comment: @Engima the minSDK Version is 10...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by using the `lsusb` command and than correcting the vendor id in 51-android.rules file and than finally restarting the adb services...

The detailed answer can be found [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/19546/9741)..